# Differentiating Apple products by their MAC addresses

Tags: iphone, ipad, mac, network, wifi

Apple has registered [a ton of MAC address ranges](http://standards.ieee.org/cgi-bin/ouisearch?infinite%20loop) for its products.  Does anyone know whether it's feasible to reliably identify which Apple product (particularly iPad, iPod, iPhone, and MacBooks) a particular device is in network traffic via specific MAC address prefixes? In other words, is there something about the MAC address of an iPad that is distinguishable from the MAC address of a MacBook, for instance?

Comment: Are you simply needing to identify wether it is a Macintosh product?

Comment: This will only work if people are not spoofing their MAC addresses. If they are, you may either get false positives or false negatives, depending on who is doing what.

Comment: Right, I understand that -- but my question wasn't whether MAC addresses are a reliable identifier, I'm asking whether I can distinguish Apple products using them.

Comment: @Christian - If they're not a reliable identifier, you **can't** distinguish Apple products using them, *as they can be changed*. So no, apparently you don't understand that. It may be possible *most* of the time, but **if the MAC has been changed, it is no longer possible**.

Comment: I don't strictly know about mac addresses, but tcp fingerprinting (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_stack_fingerprinting) can sorta get you there.  Again, as fake name was so polite in pointing out twice, fingerprinting isn't 100% reliable  (I can change my ip stack configuration) but how many people actually do.  meh   You'd at least be able to segment between iOS and non iOS products.  (based on the os fingerprint)

Comment: There is at least one company that says they can do this: /www.fing.io

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, sorting or determining a pattern in the MAC address isn't a feasible way to map to model of Apple product.

---

Over years of watching MAC addresses on networks as well as the explosion of devices on the iOS end of things, if there were a nice pattern, it would start showing in deployments with hundreds of devices.

For example, I have one Mac that has data on about 1,000 iOS devices that have been connected over time to that Mac while iPhone configuration utility was running. Looking at the data now, there are no clear patterns to help differentiate between the device types.

This also applies to Macs. Sadly, my data here is in the hundreds and not thousands presently. Yes - a string of MacBooks when ordered together will usually have sequential addresses (more so than sequential serial numbers in fact) - but over time, the iMacs seem mixed in with the Airs and the MacBook Pro.

It could be that there is some encoding present and no-one has stumbled across which bits are coded with model numbers, but a simple sort of the MAC addresses has the devices all jumbled up. Perhaps if you can find someone that runs the mobile device management software for a very large company or school district and see if they are curious enough to see if a larger data set would yield some better results for you.

I haven't seen a case where a Mac and an iOS device share the same smaller block of MAC addresses, but I can't even rule that out for you based on my experience running networks that log MAC address and are in a position to know what hardware is associated with which MAC address over the years.

My guess is the addresses are issued sequentially rather than by final destination. It would make sense to dole out parts of each region to factories that are expected to make 5 or 10 thousand devices in the next month and onle issue more once the existing addresses are consumed. If so, we might have better luck trying to bin the numbers by approximate manufacturing date rather than by where it ends up in a shipping product. Also consider on the Mac end, [repairs often give a new MAC address](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1792921) to portables and even desktop Macs when the ethernet controller is replaced.

Comment: Thanks! This is the closest yet to an answer.  We are indeed right now basically monitoring access points that have a lot of people coming through.  A quick comment: your first sentence suggests that the pattern would need to be in the last three octets, which needn't be the case given the host of prefixes Apple has, but later you mention that sorting brings out no pattern either, so you may want to clarify.  (Also, if you could s/mac/Mac/ where you mention the 1,000 iOS devices, that would help avoid confusion. :)

Comment: You've got free reign to just edit my post to clear this up to your satisfaction. I'll try to find a safe snipped of MAC that I can release showing what I mean and add that later to this post.

Answer (score 5):

Reply two years after asking, it is not feasible relying only on the Mac address.

Since you mention monitoring the network traffic,
The best approach would be to listen Bonjour traffic (multicast dns).

By default, machines are called 'jannies-iphone.local', 'gregs-macbook.local', 'peters-imac.local'...

Bonjour is pretty talkative and generate noise for AFP, SMB, VNC, RAOP, DAAP and other services/protocols. I would suggest you to use "Bonjour Browser" then script something with Tshark (Wireshark command line) to automatize the process.

**Without remote scans, you can manage your devices by :**

- Running an agent (or profile) on each OS X and iOS devices to fetch 'sysctl hw.model' or its serial number. 'Mac Tracker' can help you to
  see the different models of Mac and their spec and serial number
  pattern.
- Using Profile Manager, Configurator or any MDM solutions. (But this does not address your question).

**Find iOS and OS X running on the network :**

Also you could use a network tool such as nmap with the option -A, -O, or -sV (Active Fingerprinting and service version) and filter Apple mac addresses prefix using a network anylizer.

Looking at the service version, port numbers [tcp 65xxx being a iphone-sync port, tcp 548 AFP (OS X)] will help you to determine OS X version and Hardware but not precisely.
(You will not be able to differentiate, iPad, iPhone, and iPod, or Mac Model).

Answer (score 3):

If you are simply needing to identify whether it is a Macintosh product or not you could try the [this MAC address lookup service](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/). It allows you to type in the MAC address, and it will tell you what the vendor name is. It is not likely to be helpful in terms of identifying specific vendors for programatic use, however it has worked for me in regards to finding if the machine is an Apple product.

UPDATE:

Aside from utilizing an internal database it is not likely that you will be able to do what you are asking. If you did decide to setup an internal database it may be prudent to utilize the serial number or another unique ID available for each machine.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm looking for -- I'm looking for a way to *distinguish* Apple products via their MAC addresses.

Comment: My apologies, I read the question as you were wanting to distinguish if the MAC address was a Macintosh product.

Comment: No worries!  I realize it's a somewhat unusual question.

Comment: @E1Suave Your read of the question was my understanding also. I edited the question to clarify the OP's intent.

Comment: @DanielLawson What I thought the question was asking was interesting to me, perhaps the OP's actual question is even more interesting. I think you have edited the question very well in regards to focusing on the what the OP actually had in mind.

Comment: It's even more interesting if there's actually an answer to it. I liked your version in that it was solvable. :-)

Comment: @DanielLawson Indeed. :–) However, I am still holding out hope on an answer. It seems to me Apple likely would have an internal use for such a thing and perhaps something similar exists for consumer use.

Comment: Why would Apple encode the destination into a naming scheme when they could just maintain a database with as-built configuration to look up what MAC address was placed in which serial number product? They already have that information to print the labels on each box that list IMEI / Serial Number / Mac Address, etc...

Answer (score 3):

I was working for a worldwide known embedded computer developper/producer. As Dennis sayd (and I guess You allready known) the first three octets of six from the MAC address are for vendor's identification. Therefore u can buy adress ranges from IEEE. After them you have to guarantee as developper/vendor from your own hardware that this second part is so that the complete 6 byte MAC is entirely unique in the whole wolrd (without regarding missuse and MACspoofing for security issues later on). For lifetime of your production activity You have to guarantee that inner your 3 bytes vendor code, each code has a really unique range of adresses for second half of MAC.

### How to realize that in a continuous production?

We ve done this by assume a new adress (n+1) from our range n in{0..16'777'215} per each MAC Vendor Adress part, where n was the last given address AND the concerning unit has succesful absolved the final function test (eg. was responding in a Ethernet test bank check).

### What's MAC Address and what is it identifying?

In fact, the MAC Adress is for network layer protocoll (2nd Layer in ISO/OSI model) and used for IEE802 protocols as Ethernet,WLAN, Bluetooth and others  and refers ONLY the Network Card! NOT the machine behind! So the 2nd part of MAC is nothing else then serial production number from network chipset respectively board (e.g. WLAN or bluetooth internal extention is a small smd- printed cirquit upset on the mainboard and also serviceable).

### Examples

I have no Apple hardware arround me. But I made a check with Samsung hardware. Here are my results: (I refer only the vendor part of MAC)

1. for Samsung Galaxy S II running latest Android 4.0.4

   > 04:46:65  WLAN (802.11)  this refers to Murata Manufacturing Co. as chip-producer
   >   56:b2:a4  GSM advanced (IP over Cellphone network), not refered in my [MAC-vendor list](http://www.gcstech.net/macvendor/index.php?node=vensea&list)
2. Samsung Galaxy GT-P5110 running latest Android 4.0.4

   > 50:01:BB WLAN (802.11) not refered in my [MAC-vendor list](http://www.gcstech.net/macvendor/index.php?node=vensea&list)

Hope to give some aspect-related answers to  your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do. Using "nmap" you can find out what the device is  based on the OS or the device type. (See Below).

```
root@netmon:~# nmap -O 192.168.14.235

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-04-19 16:50 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.14.235
Host is up (0.0043s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
62078/tcp open  iphone-sync
Device type: media device|phone
Running: Apple iOS 4.X|5.X|6.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:apple:iphone_os:4 cpe:/a:apple:apple_tv:4 cpe:/o:apple:iphone_os:5 cpe:/o:apple:iphone_os:6
OS details: Apple Mac OS X 10.8.0 - 10.8.3 (Mountain Lion) or iOS 4.4.2 - 6.1.3 (Darwin 11.0.0 - 12.3.0)
Network Distance: 2 hops
```

Brought to you by OpenSource911.com

Comment: `nmap` is not a native command on macOS.

Comment: @Allan Neither is Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any official list, but you can try to compile one the way [AppleSerialNumberInfo.com](http://www.appleserialnumberinfo.com/) has done with serial numbers.  You might even approach them to do it for you.  A quick check of a few devices suggests it might be possible, as the MAC prefixes I looked at did vary by model.

Of course it will never be foolproof, as devices such as routers and switches (as well as virtual machines) routinely allow you to easily set their MAC addresses to anything you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  For the record, I fully agree that MAC addresses aren't a stable identifier, but in my setting (i) it simply doesn't matter whether a handful of people have changed them and (ii) I mainly care about distinguishing ipods from ipads from iphones, so the likelihood of people having changed them on these devices is lower still.

Comment: @Christian, I agree people probably haven't changed their iPhone MAC addresses.  More likely, someone will spoof an iPhone MAC address with a router or VM. Anyway, it sounds like you're in an environment where you can capture a lot of MAC addresses and empirically answer your own question.  If you do, please report back.

Comment: I wouldn't bet on it. Just had a quick look around the house and found both an APE and a (very old) Mac mini where the MAC address starts with 00:11:24.

Answer (score 0):

The first half of a MAC address identifies the vendor, the second half doesn't necessarily correspond to *anything*.

Comment: Bingo - this has been my experience with looking over MAC address and Apple product in general.

Answer (score 0):

No. it's not possible to differentiate between different products of Apple just by their MAC address.

You can, however, [lookup hundreds of MAC addresses](http://www.admin-toolkit.com/mac-address-lookup-manufacturer.html) very conveniently - simply paste a list of MAC addresses and it will spit out the manufacturers.

Answer (score -1):

things like a netscaler can differentiate by the browser whether it deals with an smartphen of laptop/tablet/book etc.

Answer (score -1):

It is very unlikely that you are dealing with MAC addresses only, you will almost definitely have an IP address for that device as well. When you do, you can fingerprint  the DHCP behaviour to a level of accuracy that is quite scary. Most WiFi access point vendors do this. Visit [ https://fingerbank.org ] for details on the database.